# How to resolve: The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error:

```
The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.
```

and I am not sure how to correct this..

I have a MVC5 site and in this site I have a login page.

This is the scenario that it occurs on.

1. User AAA logs in. (No issues)
2. I attempt to access a view where the user does not have access.

   - I have the class decorated with an Authorize(Roles="aa")
3. The view then logs the user off and puts them back to the login page.
4. User AAA logs in. (This time I get the error mentioned above)

To note:

I am using customErrors and this is where I see the error message.

When I log the user out I am running this method:

```
[HttpGet]
public void SignOut()
{
    IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    authenticationManager.SignOut(MyAuthentication.ApplicationCookie);
}
```

Could I possibly be missing something on the SignOut?

UPDATE:

This only occurs because of step #2 listed above.

If I log in, then log out (calling same code) then log back in, then I do not have this issue.

Comment: try adding [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute

Comment: I have that in my post method when the user logs in.          [HttpPost]      [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you've neglected to post some relevant code. The `Signout` action you have returns `void`. If you were to access this action directly in the browser, then the user would get a blank page after being signed out with no way to progress forward. As a result, I can only assume you are either calling it via AJAX or calling as a method from another action.

The way anti-forgery works in MVC is that a cookie is set on the user's machine containing a unique generated token. If the user is logged in, their username is used to compose that token. In order for a new cookie, without a username to be set, the user must be logged out *and* a new request must occur to set the new cookie. If you merely log the user out without doing a redirect or something, the new user-less cookie will not have been set yet. Then, when the user posts, the old user-based cookie is sent back while MVC is looking for the new user-less cookie, and boom: there's your exception.

Like I said, you haven't posted enough code to determine exactly why or where this is occurring, but simply, make sure there is a new request made after logging the user out, so the new cookie can be set.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.    I was not doing a redirect in this case which was causing my issue.  However I am still noticing an issue when the Authorize attribute fails it's redirecting to the login page, but I'm not quite sure how it's doing that. (It's not hitting my breakpoints)

Comment: I'm not really sure exactly what you're talking about. The default behavior of `AuthorizeAttribute` is to redirect to the URL defined either in Web.config (ASP.NET Membership) or in your Identity startup config (ASP.NET Identity). It doesn't actually log the user out, and you could technically take them to *any* page. The standard is to use sign in, so the user is presented with the opportunity to either actually sign in or authenticate with a different account that does have access.

Comment: I'm still learning MVC as I'm going but I somehow had the default behavior to log the user out.  However when the Authorize failed it repeated said behavior (logged them out but didn't redirect).  I created a custom authorization so that I could handle this and it appears to work.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the detailed explanation. The redirect is key...first going to a logout page that redirects back to login page. BUT, I found that you can save a step and have your sign-out link go directly to login page, but you must set HttpContext.User to null after doing HttpContext.SignOut() in the GET action of the login page, or else you get the Anti-forgery error. Setting the User to null seems to tell the browser that the previous cookie is dead and not to re-send it. I haven't found any problem or gotcha with it, so I'll use it until I do.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce by clicking on the login button more than once before the next View loads. I disabled the Login button after the first click to prevent the error.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.form.submit();"/>
```

Comment: This ends up failing in a user hostile way in the event of network problems resulting in the server triggered redirect never getting back to the user.  They're logged off on your server, and there's no error; but as far as they can tell the logout failed and because the button is disabled they can't try again.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the identity check the anti-forgery validation performs. Add the following to your Application_Start method:

`AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true.`

Comment: When I added that line I get the error: The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "AAA" but the current user is ""

Comment: Don't know but mine it was working. Try this in your action [OutputCache(NoStore=true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam= "None")]

Comment: `AntiForgeryConfig` auto-complete does not give me an option to select `SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks`.  I'm using Asp .NET Web API

Comment: Should probably include the comment of "Use caution when setting this value. Using it improperly can open security vulnerabilities in the application." from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/jj158419(v=vs.111)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public ActionResult Login(string modelState = null)
{
    if (modelState != null)
        ModelState.AddModelError("", modelState);

    return View();
}
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Controller", new { modelState = "MSG_USER_NOT_CONFIRMED" });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I haved similar problem. I found this text "@Html.AntiForgeryToken() " in my project in 2 place. And one plase will was in "view file"  Views - test.cshtml.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @if (@Model.interviewed)
...
```

I deleted this code line ("@Html.AntiForgeryToken() ") and working fine.

PS: But I am not delete this code in file _LoginPartial.cshtml.
Good luck!